# Change created_at value in collection to be carbon human readable

Tags: laravel, collections, php-carbon

I'm trying to output a collections created_at time to be human readable for a JSON request.

The following code works:

```
$childComments = $comment->getParentsChildren($comment->id , $childCount)->with('creator')->get();

return $childComments->map(function($childComments){
    return [
        'created_at' => $childComments->created_at->diffForHumans()
    ];
});
```

The problem is that just returns created_at and I would like to return the rest of the $childComments collection without having to add each property manually.

I've tried this:

```
return $childComments->map(function($childComments){

    $childComments->created_at = $childComments->created_at->diffForHumans();

});
```

And get this error thrown.

> {message: "A two digit month could not be found↵Data missing", exception: "InvalidArgumentException",…}
>   exception
>   :
>   "InvalidArgumentException"
>   file
>   :
>   "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/community/vendor/nesbot/carbon/src/Carbon/Carbon.php"

**Edit Accessor Attempt:**

**Controller**

```
return $childComments->each(function($childComments){

    $childComments->created_at = $childComments->humanDate;

});
```

**Comment Model**

```
public function getHumanDate()
{
    return $this->created_at->diffForHumans();
}
```

I'm now getting null on all the created_at dates in the JSON output.

Comment: Have you tried "Accessor"? [Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators)

Comment: @RouhollahMazarei I have not, but would that to effect everywhere I use created_at?

Comment: Yes, I've used it in almost all my project to convert date to Jalali date. I strongly recommend to use it.

Comment: I would only like to only affect this one instance of created_at and not others. Can I still do that with an accessor?

Comment: You can create accessor for each model you want. Just try it. You need to add only 3-5 lines in your model, so try it.

Comment: @RouhollahMazarei, I just edited my question with an accessor attempt and am getting null with created_at

Comment: Change the function name in the model to `getHumanDateAttribute` then use it in the template like `{{ $childComment->humanDate }}`. There is no need to walk the collection. Treat it as any other attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Correction:** Eloquent converts timestamp fields to and from Carbon objects.  A diff can't be parsed into a new Carbon object.

An easy solution is just to rename this field to something like `created_diff` so the model doesn't try to parse it.

You also need to return the object from the map closure, otherwise, the collection will just be filled with null values:

```
return $childComments->map(function($childComments){
    $childComments->created_diff = $childComments->created_at->diffForHumans();
    return $childComments;
});
```

Or since objects are mutable and passed by reference, you could also just use each:

```
return $childComments->each(function($childComments){
    $childComments->created_diff = $childComments->created_at->diffForHumans();
});
```